# apex test class, when testing, the error message is System.StringException: Invalid id:Class.speakerCRControllerTest.testSpeakerCRController: line 21

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public without sharing class speakerCRController {
    //更新第三方信息
    public static User u=[Select Id,Name from User where Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
    @AuraEnabled   
    public static string updateThirdPartyInfos(String recordId,String ThirdPartyComments){
        try {
            DebugLog.saveDebugLogs('recordId:'+recordId + ' ThirdPartyComments:'+ThirdPartyComments,'DEBUG' );
            Speaker_Change_Request__c scr=[select Id,Comments__c from Speaker_Change_Request__c where Id=:recordId];
            scr.Comments__c=ThirdPartyComments;
            update scr;
            String message=ApprovalProcessController.processAction(recordId,'Approve','');
            return message;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return parseReturnMessage.parseErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //请求附加信息
    @AuraEnabled   
    public static string requestAdditionalInfos(String recordId,String additionalInfos){
        try {
            Speaker_Change_Request__c scr=[select Id,AdditionalInfos__c,RDcomments__c,Approval_Status__c from Speaker_Change_Request__c where Id=:recordId];
            if(additionalInfos == Null){
                additionalInfos = '';
            }
            if(scr.AdditionalInfos__c == NULL){
                scr.AdditionalInfos__c='审批人-'+u.Name+'：'+additionalInfos;
            }else {
                scr.AdditionalInfos__c = scr.AdditionalInfos__c +'\r' + '审批人-'+u.Name+'：'+additionalInfos;
            }
            scr.RDcomments__c = additionalInfos;
            scr.Approval_Status__c='Revision Draft';
            update scr;
            return parseReturnMessage.returnSuccessMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return parseReturnMessage.parseErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //确认提交额外信息
    @AuraEnabled   
    public static string executeSubmitAdditionalInfos(String recordId,String additionalInfos){
        try {
            Speaker_Change_Request__c scr=[select Id,AdditionalInfos__c,CurrentApprovalStatus__c,Approval_Status__c from Speaker_Change_Request__c where Id=:recordId];
            scr.Approval_Status__c=scr.CurrentApprovalStatus__c;
            if(additionalInfos == Null){
                additionalInfos = '';
            }
            if(scr.AdditionalInfos__c == NULL){
                scr.AdditionalInfos__c='申请人-'+u.Name+'：'+additionalInfos;
            }else {
                scr.AdditionalInfos__c = scr.AdditionalInfos__c +'\r' + '申请人-'+u.Name+'：'+additionalInfos;
            }
            // scr.AdditionalInfos__c =scr.AdditionalInfos__c +'\r' + '申请人-'+u.Name+'：'+additionalInfos;
            update scr;
            return parseReturnMessage.returnSuccessMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debuglog.saveDebuglogs('Error:'+ e.getMessage() +' line:'+e.getLineNumber(),'ERROR');
            return parseReturnMessage.parseErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public without sharing class speakerCRControllerTest {
    @isTest static void testSpeakerCRController(){
        //user
        Profile TestProfile = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile where name = 'Engage Standard User'];
        user TestUser = new User();
        TestUser.Username = 'TestUser.@163.com';
        TestUser.LastName = 'Test';
        TestUser.Email = '123456@163.com';
        TestUser.Alias = 'Test1';
        TestUser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'Asia/Shanghai';
        TestUser.LocaleSidKey = 'zh_CN';
        TestUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        TestUser.ProfileId = TestProfile.id;
        TestUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'zh_CN';
        //account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.LastName = 'test';
        account.OCE__ProfessionalTitle__c = '主任医师';
        account.OCE__Department__c = '呼吸科';
        account.RecordTypeId = UtilTest.getRecordTypeIdByDevName('Account', 'MP');
        //speaker
        String SpeakerRecordType = '';
        List<RecordType> RecordTypeList = [SELECT id,DeveloperName,SobjectType FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName IN ('HCP-中国大陆地区执业的内地居民主要执业地在中国大陆的中国籍讲者(包含在职、退休HCP)') AND SobjectType = 'OCE__Speaker__c' ];
        for(RecordType rt : RecordTypeList) {
           if(rt.DeveloperName == 'HCP-中国大陆地区执业的内地居民主要执业地在中国大陆的中国籍讲者(包含在职、退休HCP)') {
           SpeakerRecordType = rt.id;
           }
        }
        OCE__Speaker__c speaker = new OCE__Speaker__c();
        speaker.Name = 'test';
        speaker.OCE__Account__c = account.id;
        speaker.RecordTypeId = SpeakerRecordType;
        speaker.Nationality__c = '中国';
        speaker.Academic_Title__c = '主任医师';
        speaker.OCE__Tier__c = '国际级';
        speaker.Medical_Institution_Name__c = '北京大学人民医院';
        speaker.OCE__Status__c = 'Active';
        speaker.Association_Title__c = '中国医师协会内分泌分会主委';
        insert speaker;
        //SpeakerChangeRequest
        String SCRRecordType = '';
        List<RecordType> RecordTypeList1 = [SELECT id,DeveloperName,SobjectType FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName IN ('HCP-中国大陆执业中国籍') AND SobjectType = 'Speaker_Change_Request__c' ];
        for(RecordType rt : RecordTypeList1) {
           if(rt.DeveloperName == 'HCP-中国大陆执业中国籍') {
           SCRRecordType = rt.id;
           }
        }

        Speaker_Change_Request__c SCR = new Speaker_Change_Request__c();
        SCR.RecordTypeId = SCRRecordType;
        SCR.Speaker__c = speaker.id;
        SCR.Comments__c = 'test';
        SCR.Approval_Status__c = 'None';
        SCR.RDcomments__c = '';
        SCR.AdditionalInfos__c = null;
        SCR.CurrentApprovalStatus__c = '';
        insert SCR;
        Test.startTest();
        speakerCRController.updateThirdPartyInfos(SCR.id,'Test');   
        speakerCRController.requestAdditionalInfos(SCR.id, 'Test1');
        speakerCRController.executeSubmitAdditionalInfos(SCR.id, 'Test2');
        Test.stopTest();

    }   
}
```

Comment: In your test class Can you check if you are getting correct recordtype Id for the Account from the below code. I hope this might me causing the issue. `account.RecordTypeId = UtilTest.getRecordTypeIdByDevName('Account', 'MP');`

Comment: Hello, following your advice, I re-wrote one without calling the method in another class, the problem is solved. Thank you, this is my first time asking a question.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I have added same as the Answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment there seems to be issue in the below line.

```
account.RecordTypeId = UtilTest.getRecordTypeIdByDevName('Account', 'MP');
```

The above line is not giving the record type id of the Account because of which you are getting the error.

Can you call the other class properly or rewrite the code and get the recordtype id directly.